# Use VLOOKUP to search among multiple text synonyms criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GIk4.png

Hello, I am needing to using VLOOKUP to search amung multiple crtiera, multiple synonyms, and output a value based on table inputs. For example, image 1 is the list of synonyms that will have a subsequent value in another table. I would like the function to look for ANY of those names and output the value in the corresponding VLOOKUP column for each Sample. I have tried this:

```
=VLOOKUP(OR(C$2=TRUE,C$3=TRUE,C$4=TRUE,C$5=TRUE,C$6=TRUE,C$7=TRUE,C$8=TRUE)=TRUE,'[Worksheet2.xlsx]BD-7 1'!$F$1:$G$73,2)
```

but am not getting any luck. It doesn't look like VLOOKUP appreciates using multiple criteria. Thank you for any help!

Comment: SUMPRODUCT function?

Answer (score 0):

1. VLOOKUP() finds ONE item (first argument) in a list,
2. the list is in the first column of the array you have as second argument,
3. the third argument tells which column to pick from your array, 1= return the item matching
4. and the last argument is to be FALSE to have it try find an EXACT match.

Now with that said: You can type in any (single one) of the synonyms, or even a match pattern[1] to find.

The value or item to return can be in any column to the right of the first (included in the array definition), or the first column.

[1] `*` for multiple possible characters, `?` for a single one

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand how it works now. Here is what my code and errors look like. https://i.imgur.com/dS2QJsX.png I now need a way to join/add these rows saying 2, N/A, N/A. How can I do that? SUM(fx) doesn't work.

Comment: I am trying this: SUMIF(VLOOKUP(C1:C3,C13:D14,2,FALSE),"<>#N/A")

Answer (score 0):

Your solution in the comments to `Hannu`'s answer should work fine. The below might be considered slightly more transparent, and it would allow for trapping of more errors. (However, trapping more errors might hide problems you'd rather spot and solve, though that's not necessarily a concern if your data (lookup values OR return values data sets) is decent and will likely always be decent.)

```
=SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1:C3,C13:D14,2,FALSE),0))
```

It uses `IFERROR()` to trap the failed lookups and give them a zero value so adding nothing to the sum you desire and then `SUM()` simply adds them all up.

(Possibly it might be faster but possibly not. Probably not a concern if the lookup happens in a single place, but if calculated for all of a data set it could matter, depending upon its size.)